# Australian spousal VISA refused, grounds to appeal?

Tags: visa, immigration, australia, uk-citizens

I'm from the UK and my wife is Australian. I applied for a spousal VISA in 2009 which was granted (provisionally). We lived in Australia for about a year before returning to the UK.

We then visited at Christmas 2014 returning to the UK in January 2015.

Today I had an email informing me that my spousal visa application has been refused because I did not respond to a request for information that was sent in January 2015. I cannot find any trace of this request.

Will I be able to appeal this decision? I would like to avoid having to reapply as it is an expensive and lengthy process.

Comment: I don't know how expensive and lengthy the application process is, but I would suspect that it is quicker, cheaper and more likely to succeed than an appeal. Just make sure to include the information that you didn't supply the first time. (I suspect an appeal would only succeed if you supplied the information and they lost it. )

Comment: I don't even know what this information was as I never received the request for it. It is not information missing from the initial application. I suspect you are correct regarding the appeal process though.

Comment: My close vote: without the specifics as to what was missing, it would be difficult to respond, especially 2 years after the fact.